# Why is a2p (Awk to Perl translator) installed by default? Why would I want to convert Awk to Perl?

Tags: command-line, awk, perl, command

I am surprised to see the `a2p` utility installed by default in my Linux distribution.

`a2p` is a command line utility that converts an *Awk* program from *standard input* to a *perl* program that it outputs to *standard output*.

Why would I ever want to convert an *Awk* program to a *Perl* program when I have an *Awk* interpreter installed?

Why is it that *Linux* distributions include `a2p` in their default installations?

Comment: Ask the developers/maintainers of whatever distro it is that you are using, it is their call...

Comment: Because it's part of perl, and perl is installed by default in Linux.

Comment: One example use would be where folk find themselves with old legacy awk scripts which need to do something funky for which awk doesn't have functionality.  Bring it into the modern age with a2p and hey presto you've got all the magic of perl at your fingertips.

Comment: @don_crissti: Ah yeah, it's part of perl source, but the dev/maintainer of the distro can exclude it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use these tools to increase the efficiency of `perl` scripts.

You would want to do this if you had a larger `perl` program and you wanted to integrate the functionality of an `awk` script without calling a subprocess.  You would call `a2p` and integrate the generated code into an existing perl script.

There's a similar utility, `find2perl` which takes a `find` command line and generates `perl` code to do the same thing, avoiding the call to a `find` subprocess.

These are optimization tools for `perl` scripts.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why it got installed by default ? : Its upto developer/maintainer of the distro that you are using.
2. Why would you need `a2p`

> There is an awk idiom of putting int() around a string expression to force numeric interpretation, even though the argument is always integer anyway. This is generally unneeded in perl, but a2p can't tell if the argument is always going to be integer, so it leaves it in. You may wish to remove it.
>
> Perl differentiates numeric comparison from string comparison. Awk has one operator for both that decides at run time which comparison to do. A2p does not try to do a complete job of awk emulation at this point. Instead it guesses which one you want. It's almost always right, but it can be spoofed. All such guesses are marked with the comment "#??? ". You should go through and check them. You might want to run at least once with the -w switch to perl, which will warn you if you use == where you should have used eq.

For more information : [A2P](http://perldoc.perl.org/a2p.html)

Comment: To be honest , I copied this from A2P documentation , so all credits to them.